# Rails FriendlyId for friendly url for category and subcategory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-url, friendly-id

In Rails4 is it possible to have FriendlyId build out the complete url including categories and subcategories?

Example:
**sitename/categories/6/subcategories/36/12**

should be:
**sitename/community/events/garage-sale-in-fresno**
Community is the category, events is the subcategory
-OR-
**sitename/nevada/las-vegas/woodshed-rib-shack-bbq**
Nevada is the category, Las Vegas is the subcategory

I see how to create slugs for the individual listings, but it would be nice to have a way to create the complete url in 'friendly' format.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this using rails RESTful helpers, you need to define your own route:

```
get ':category_name/:subcategory_name/:id', to: '<your_controller>#<controller_action>'
```

Since this url signature will match many of your other routes, make sure it is placed after all the routes it can collide with (like /admin/login/failed), ideally at the end of the routes.rb file.

Comment: Wow!  That is not what I expected as a solution.  I will experiment with it right away.  Thanks for the great tip.